# Variables in MySql raw queries

Tags: mysql, reactjs, laravel

I have this raw query that generates a CSV, and it is returning 2 dates in 'hardcode mode' I would like to replace these values ​​with variables how do I do? In this case, it would be the variables injected by the 'post' with the Axios coming from a component of React.js. The query is running successfully and the react component is working good too.

**Laravel(Version 5.8) file:**

```
//...rest of the code omitted

$api->get('orders1/csv1', function () {      
    
   $sql= DB::select(DB::raw(    
    "
   SELECT orders.id,

//... rest of the query ommited      
// this 2 dates above are needed to be replaced by variables      
      WHERE tr.tenant_relations_type = 'App\\Models\\Order'
      AND orders.created_at BETWEEN '2021-01-01 00:00:00' and '2021-06-07 00:00:00' AND 
//... rest of the query ommited      
   
   "));    
    return (new Response(json_encode($sql), 200))->header('Content-Type', 'text/csv' );    
});
//... rest of the code omitted
```

**ReactJS file:**

//... rest of the code omitted

```
const saveCsv = (data, cb) => {
    axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_EASYMUNDI_URL}/api/orders1/csv1`, data, {
        headers: { Authorization: AuthStr }
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        cb(response);
        console.log('response: ')
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        cb({
          error: true,
          message: error.message,
          status: error.response && error.response.status ? error.response.status : ''
        });
      });
  };

  // .. rest of the code omitted
```

As I said before, this component is working successfully. In the 'console.log', the response is returning the two dates that came from an input of form. My challenge is to link these dates in query variables. How do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In queries defined by `DB::select()` you can use parameters defined in array.

```php
$sql = DB::select(DB::raw("  
  SELECT orders.id,
  // ...  
  WHERE tr.tenant_relations_type = 'App\\Models\\Order'
  AND orders.created_at BETWEEN :dateFrom and :dateTo 
  // ...    
"), [
  'dateFrom' => $request->input('dateForm'),
  'dateTo' => $request->input('dateTo'),
]);
```

Of course you should additionally filter input dates to make sure are in valid format.

Answer (score 0):

Use bindings for the variables

```
$startDate = '2021-01-01 00:00:00';
$endDate = '2021-06-07 00:00:00';
$sql= DB::select(DB::raw(    
    "
   SELECT orders.id,

//... rest of the query ommited          
      WHERE tr.tenant_relations_type = ?
      AND orders.created_at BETWEEN ? and ? AND 
//... rest of the query ommited      
   
   ", [Order::class, $startDate, $endDate]));//place your variables in order here
```

if you dont want to track the order of the bindings, you can use an associative array.

```
$sql= DB::select(DB::raw(    
    "
   SELECT orders.id,

//... rest of the query ommited          
      WHERE tr.tenant_relations_type = :model
      AND orders.created_at BETWEEN :start and :end AND 
//... rest of the query ommited      
   
   "; ['start' => $startDate, 'end' => $endDate, 'model' => Order::class]));
```